# how to compile lex/yacc files on windows "without cygwin"

Tags: cygwin, bison, flex-lexer

We need to create .c file from .l (lax) and .y (yacc) file using visual studio 1o on windows 2008.
We cant use Cygwin at all.
Where does Flex and bison come into picture here ? Even Flex and Bison use cygwin internally or not ?
how are we supposed to go about it ?

Comment: Did you try something like http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/ ?

Comment: mingw comes with flex/bison packages that don't use cygwin at all.  Bison is GPL so will always be under a GNU license.  Flex is BSD-like licensed, and not GPL.  [Berkeley yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Yacc) is available under a BSD-like license

Answer (score 1):

You can download a windows version of [flex from sourceforge](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/flex.htm) and [bison from sourceforge](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bison.htm), you then need to add them to the PATH environment variable. Be sure not to have a space in the install directory (i.e. do not put in C:\Program Files\ etc). You can then build the output with CL from visual studio command line tools if you wish.

As previously mentioned MinGw is another option.

I have even made a [YouTube Video showing the install of these packages](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58I6nAybzzI)!